# How to write RAW data to a file using Java? e.g same as: nc -l 8000 > capture.raw

Tags: java, linux, file-io

In TCP i am receiving media stream from an IP camera as RAW. According to there advise, i need to write that as file. And then i can play it with media player such as VLC.

But when i write this to a file, and play with media players it never play corrupted.

After comparing the original file i see my Java writing it in wrong characters. And there sample file shows different. What or how do i fix such file writing issue, here is how i am writing it:

```
byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
int bytes_read = 0;
try {  
    bytes_read = sock.getInputStream().read(buf, 0, buf.length);                
    String data = new String(buf, 0, bytes_read);                   
    System.err.println("DATA: " +  bytes_read + " bytes, data=" +data);

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
            new FileWriter("capture.ogg", true));
        out.write(data);
        out.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right... at least until the part where you turn your `byte[]` into a `String`:

That step only really makes sense if your `byte[]` represents textual data in the first place! Which it **doesn't**!

*Whenever* you handle binary data *or* don't actually care what the data represents you must *avoid* using `String`/`Reader`/`Writer` to handle that data. Instead **do use** `byte[]`/`InputStream`/`OutputStream`.

Also, you *must* read from the socket in a loop, because nothing guarantees that you've read everything:

```
byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
int bytes_read;
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("capture.ogg", true);
InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
while ((bytes_read = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    out.write(buf, 0, bytes_read);
}
out.close();
```

Comment: I believe it should be: "out.write(buf, 0, bytes_read);", not "out.write(data, 0, bytes_read);"

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use `Readers`, `Writers` and `Strings` for binary data. Stick with `InputStreams` and `OutputStreams`.

I.e., change

- `BufferedWriter` -> `BufferedOutputStream`,
- `FileWriter` -> `FileOutputStream`
- and instead of `String`, just use a `byte[]`.

If you're dealing with sockets, I must advice you to look into the [NIO package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) though.

Comment: I second the 'Look at NIO' notion.  It *may* be an overly complex solution to a simple problem, but then again, it may not.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it written limits the output file to a maximum size of 1024 bytes.  Try a loop:

```
    try {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int bytes_read = 0;
        InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("capture.ogg"));

        do {
            bytes_read = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
            System.out.println("Just Read: " + bytes_read + " bytes");

            if (bytes_read < 0) {
                /* Handle EOF however you want */
            }

            if (bytes_read > 0)
                  out.write(buf, 0, bytes_read);

        } while (bytes_read >= 0);

        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
```