# Sending files over Sockets android and C#

Tags: c#, android, server, client

So I'm facing this very very weird problem. I'm building a server in C# on my computer and I have my android phone connected on the same WiFi and they are communicating. I'm trying to send a file from the PC to the phone. Everything works as expected only though some files jam the process. After debugging for quite a while I can't seem to understand what's causing the issue.
Here is the sever sending function:

```
 public void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        int read;
        int totalWritten = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        /*while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            totalWritten += read;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            output.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine("Write: " + read + " so far wrote: " + totalWritten);
        }*/
        int bt;
        while ((bt = input.ReadByte()) != -1)
            output.WriteByte((byte)bt);
        totalWritten++;
    }
    private void sendFile(NetworkStream stream, FileInfo fi)
    {
        readyForNext = false;
        String msg2 = ("SMD;;FileName:" + fi.Name + "!FileSize:" + fi.Length + "EMD;;");
        byte[] metadata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg2);
        stream.Write(metadata, 0, metadata.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        String fileContent = "SFC;;";
        metadata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileContent);
        stream.Write(metadata, 0, metadata.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(fi.FullName);
        //reader.CopyTo(stream);
        Console.WriteLine("Sending: " + fi.Name + " Size: " + fi.Length);
        CopyStream(reader, stream);
        reader.Close();
        stream.Flush();
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
```

This is in C#, the quoted code parts are other attempts I've made. Here is the receiving end:

```
private void readerFunc() throws IOException {
    int c;
    currentMessage = new StringBuffer();
    while (-1 != (c = mIn.read())) {
        if(!isReceivingFile) {
            currentMessage.append((char) c);
            if (currentMessage.toString().contains(Consts.START_META_DATA)) {
                isReceivingMetaData = true;
                newFile();
                currentMessage = new StringBuffer();
            } else if (currentMessage.toString().contains(Consts.END_META_DATA)) {
                isReceivingMetaData = false;
                String metadataMEssage = currentMessage.toString().replace(Consts.END_META_DATA, "");
                if (!parseMetadata(metadataMEssage)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error parsing metadata: " + metadataMEssage);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Parsed: " + currentFileName + " Size: " + mFileSize);
                }
                currentMessage = new StringBuffer();
            } else if (currentMessage.toString().contains(Consts.START_FILE_CONTENT)) {
                isReceivingFile = true;
                mNfw = new NetFileWriter(mPath + File.separator + currentFileName);
                bytesLeft = mFileSize;
                Log.d(TAG,"Starting with: " + bytesLeft);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(bytesLeft > 0)
            {
                bytesLeft--;
                mNfw.write(c);
                Log.d(TAG,"Left to read: " + bytesLeft);
            }
            if(bytesLeft == 0){
                Log.d(TAG,"Finished: " + bytesLeft);
                isReceivingFile = false;
                currentMessage = new StringBuffer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As said, it's working for SOME files, what I get stuck on is that I'm trying to send a file that has a size of 131,172 bytes (the code works for at least 500KB files, tested). I check in the debugger and I see that the server (C#) sends over 131172 bytes. I see the client (Java, Android Studio) receiving the size (131172) and in the debugging process I'm writing to logcat how many bytes are left to read. The server finishes it's file sending and the client is ALWAYS missing 1516 bytes for that specific file. I've tried removing it from my list to make sure it's not just this file, and it happens again later on, on a different file. I've tried many attempts of reading a single byte, full buffer and such but I always end up getting the same error. I was thinking maybe because the Android phone is a linux OS and my computer is W10, maybe they calculate the file size differently, if anyone knows something like this and might share some info with me, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: You are sending binary data.  How do you know at receive end when all the data is received?  You need to add a byte count at beginning of the send message and then on receive end stop when you get all the bytes based on the count.  You are sending TCP and it is possible to get and receive packet with zero length so never use "> 0" to test for end of data.

Comment: What kind of file are you sending? Text/plain or images or pdf? On the receiving side you use a string buffer. You can only do that for plain text. Not for images and such.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. I'm sending a Metadata message that tells me what's the file size. The problem is, say the file size is 131172, if I attempt to read that much bytes (in chunks of course because I can't eat up all the ram) I end up getting stuck because the reader is waiting for 1516 more bytes to be written into the stream

Comment: @blackapps Hmmm, I see what you mean, the point is to transfer any type of file, I'll try modify the code to work on pure bytes and not chars

Comment: Further you are sending and receiving bytes one by one. That will take a lor of time.

Comment: `say the file size is 131172, if I attempt to read that much bytes (in chunks of course because I can't eat up all the ram) I end up getting stuck because the reader is waiting for 1516 more bytes to be written into the stream` Well then you do something wrong. Why would the reader wait for 1516 bytes more? It should stop when 131172 bytes are read.

Comment: File size is irrelevant as you should just send an amount of bytes. And the receiver will receive that amount. Just write all bytes directly to file and you transfered your file.

Comment: Your receiving code is so complicated that it is impossible to see what you do

Comment: @blackapps I tried with 1 byte at a time to maybe catch the error I'm doing, that's not gonna stay like this obviously. And that's what I'm saying the error is, the server is saying it finished sending 131172 bytes. The client says it only read 129656 bytes (missing 1516) and then hangs, waiting for the remaining bytes. And this is what I'm trying to figure out, why are there missing bytes, where do I lose them

Comment: At the sending side you use a reader. Readers are for plain text. Better just take a simple input stream. Also  the sender should not mess around with encoding or ascii. The only thing that is relevant are the bytes of the file. Just send them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234147/discussion-between-dan-baruch-and-blackapps).

Comment: No chat.........

Comment: `FileStream reader ....` That confused me ;-)

Comment: `totalWritten++;` That will be equal to 1 when file sent. Compare with fi.Length.

Comment: Oh, no it was there for debugging too, I ended up not using it at all anyway

Answer (score 0):

As blackapps stated in the comments, this error was resulted because I've used string-based operations and not raw data, I guess that during the converting of the data some bytes were lost and that caused the bug. I've changed everything to work with plain bytes and now it's working fine (Basically changed according to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7648503